# What exactly is "noonday night"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, time, archaicisms

In [answering](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28520/is-there-a-term-for-midnight-that-is-like-noon/28571#28571) the question *[Is there a term for “midnight” that is like “noon”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28520/5822)*, I came across the phrase *noonday night* listed as a synonym for *midnight* in my copy of *Roget's International Thesaurus*—attributed to Longfellow. I included the reference in my answer, but after reading the [passage](http://books.google.com/books?id=s6k4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA51&dq=longfellow%20noonday%20night&hl=en&ei=gYTqTbGCL-jX0QH8xvWPAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBA#v=snippet&q=noonday%20night&f=false) more carefully, I'm not so sure it is referring to the middle of the night. Searching this phrase turns up [many](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22noonday%20night%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22noonday%20night%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=JRHrTeLtEoL3gAel-bzYCQ&start=0&sa=N&fp=fff3594d9bc016f&biw=1280&bih=705) usages by other authors, but I'm unable to determine from them what exactly is being referred to.

I'm wondering if it could be a description of an eclipse, or some permutation of the [midnight sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_sun) phenomenon. Can anyone offer some insight? What did this phrase originally mean and when was it first used?

Comment: Wow, didn't know *Roget's* was still popular in this day and age :)

Comment: @Jimi: Ol' Roget has earned me a healthy bit of rep on this site ;)

Answer (score 6):

The Longfellow quote refers to the passage in the Iliad (which of course you remember), when one of the gods causes a thick fog to cover the battlefield at midday.
www.hellenica.de says

> Ajax's prayer to Zeus, to remove the fog which has descended on the battle - even if the Greeks are destined to lose - to allow them to die in the light, has become proverbial.

So "noonday night" is no more an idiom than Koestler's "Darkness at Noon": it's just an expressive description.

Comment: And just to be clear, it's an expressive description **of darkness at midday**. It is ***not*** a synonym for midnight.

Answer (score 4):

It could be a description of an eclipse, or a terrible storm that darkens the midday sky as if it were night.

Supporting this interpretation is a Sir Richard Blackmore quote in the 1710 *The Art of English Poetry* by Edward Bysshe

> A suddain Storm did from the South arise,
>   And horrid black begun to hang the Skies:
>   Low-bellying Clouds soon intercept the Light,
>   And o'er the Sailors spread a noon-day Night..

This verse is quoted again in one of the later editions of *De rarum natura* and later in *A complete edition of the poets of Great Britain* (1795) by Robert Anderson.

There is little context in the Longfellow poem, 'Supernatural darkness' also does not imply night-time.  It appears to be a mistake in *Roget's Thesaurus*.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtiw0.png

Comment: @Martha I had the wrong Longfellow poem and I missed the Ajax connection but the answer in the end is the same.

Answer (score 3):

In Benny Hester's 1990 [*Rubber Canoe*](http://locket.net/rubbercanoe/l_unitedwestand.html#noondaynight), lyrics:

> It's *the dead of the night*
>
> Just an L.A. night
> New Orleans night
> It's a New York night
> Miami
> night
>
> Call it a *noonday
> night*

As I found out, "Dead of night" and "noonday night" are synonyms,  maybe refer to night times are filled by many mysterious scary things that we are not able to see.

Comment: The phrase seems to be used more metaphorically in this song as a term for "spiritual blindness." I haven't seen this use of the phrase elsewhere.

Comment: @Gigili I had no idea how popular this song was! It accounts for many recent instances of the expression noonday night. I am more inclined to think of "noonday night" as a metaphor for an eclipse (I have found a few examples of that too). But the lyrics in this song are more prominent than I ever realized until I read this answer yesterday!

Answer (score 2):

Well, since *[noonday](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/noonday)* is a synonym for noon, *noonday of night* may be a synonym for midnight. Although I haven't found any solid proof for it, except for [this](http://www.definition-of.net/noon+of+night) (and it's *noon of night*, not *noonday of night*).

Interestingly, I've also found this [definition of noonday night](http://thesaurasize.com/noonday+night):

> °A flavored sugar preparation, used for icing cakes.
>
> °Dark chocolate.

Comment: The expression is actually "noonday night" - no "of".